# Why array is not getting sorted?

Tags: javascript

Why `nums` array is not getting sorted? How does `>` or `<` operator works inside `sort` method as in the below code?

```js
    const nums = [1, 2, 5, 45, 22, 48, 11];
    console.log(nums);      // [1, 2, 5, 45, 22, 48, 11]

    nums.sort((a, b) => a > b);
    console.log(nums);      // [1, 2, 5, 45, 22, 48, 11]
```

Comment: For me it looks sorted

Comment: @Jens — 48 does not come before 11

Comment: "_How does > or < operator works inside sort_" They don't work in sort method. The method expects a "tri-state" number, that is negative (less than), zero (equal) or positive (greater than).

Comment: the function passed to `sort()` is not expected to return boolean, but a postive/negative or zero number.

Comment: @Quentin yes it is in the comment of OP. But not in the output of the code

Comment: @Jens — It is when I test it. (But the sort algorithm isn't stable)

Comment: `return a - b;` will help you

Comment: your snippet is working fine. The second console.log shows `[
  1,
  2,
  5,
  11,
  22,
  45,
  48
]`

Comment: @Teemu #TZHX Apparently the source code I was looking at had it written like that so I was confused.

Comment: Well, one of the easiest way to learn how the things work in JavaScript is to [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) at MDN, you can't rely on arbitrary code examples found from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can subtract b from a

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 5, 45, 22, 48, 11];
nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(nums);
```